# Trying to target a JSON object within an object, within an object... in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, parsing

I have this json blob I am trying to map over:

```
{
    "pdns": [
      {
        "id":6,
        "code":"\nfrom trutils.spark import pdns\nimport json\ndf = pdns.query(values=\"c.ipts.com\", start=\"2018-02-01\", end=\"2018-02-02\")\nrecords = df.collect()\nparsed_records = [[record.domain, record.addr, record.type, record['count'], record.lastSeen] for record in records]\nprint(json.dumps(parsed_records))\n",
        "state":"available",
        "output":{
                  "status":"ok",
                  "execution_count":6,
                  "data":{
                            "text/plain":"[[\"c.ipts.com\", \"198.11.168.38\", \"A\", 11, 1517516700]]"
                         }
                  },
        "progress":1.0
      }
    ]
   },
```

In my table I am unsure of how to target the array of data within "text/plain". I need to individually parse out those items in the array into individual cells.

Here is my current code for my table:

```
<tbody>
                    {this.state.gvEntries.map(pdns => (
                      <tr>
                          <td>{}</td>
                          <td>{}</td>
                          <td>{}</td>
                          <td>{}</td>
                          <td>{}</td>
                      </tr>
                     ))}
                    </tbody>
```

And here is how I am fetching the data in the component above. I have gotten this all to work with the first layer of objects.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);  
    this.state = { gvEntries: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/mockData/")
    .then(pdns => pdns.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({ gvEntries: data[4].pdns }));
  }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON.parse can be used to parse the JSON object string into an object.  To map this data into a table, try the following code:

```
<tbody>
  {
    JSON.parse(this.state.gvEntries[0]['output']['data']['text/plain'])[0].map(row => (
      <tr>
        <td>{row}</td>
      </tr>
    ))
  }
</tbody>
```

Essentially, what I'm doing here is attempting to use JSON.parse to convert your JSON string into a JSON object. `this.state.gvEntries[0]['output']['data']['text/plain']` is how I am attempting to access your JSON string.  After running that value through JSON.parse() I target the first element in the array (because it looks like its an array within an array) and give each element it's own row in the table.

I'm assuming the JSON blob you show is equivalent to `this.state.gvEntries`

Comment: I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined and what exactly would an example of the <td>{row).}</td> be??? It's throwing me an error on that too

Comment: What does your this.state.gvEntires data look like? I'm assuming it's `[
      {
        "id":6,
        "code":"\nfrom trutils.spark...",
        "state":"available",
        "output":{
                  "status":"ok",
                  "execution_count":6,
                  "data":{
                            "text/plain":"[[\"c.ipts.com\", \"198.11.168.38\", \"A\", 11, 1517516700]]"
                         }
                  },
        "progress":1.0
      }
    ]`

Comment: <td>{row).}</td> was me hitting enter before looking at what I wrote haha.  My bad.

Comment: this.state.gvEntries data[4] is a the json blob above, and there are about 7 other entries in the encompassing file. All objects I will map out in different tables. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Forgive me for all the edits, but this should be alot closer to how this works.  Just in case, I added a comment that explains my thought process on how to convert the string into a mappable array.

Comment: You're fine I appreciate the help but I am unforunately still getting that property 'data' of undefined error. I must be still doing something wrong

Comment: You're string is nested pretty deep into the this.state.gvEntries array.  You just have to get to that string and run it through JSON.parse to convert it into an object where you can map over it.

Comment: I just ran it through my console and it works.  If you console.log(this.state.gvEntries) and it is an array then the code I posted above should work. :|

Comment: I'm assuming the shape of this.state.gvEntries looks like: `[
      {
        "id":6,
        "code":"\nfrom ...",
        "state":"available",
        "output":{
                  "status":"ok",
                  "execution_count":6,
                  "data":{
                            "text/plain":"[[\"c.ipts.com\", \"198.11.168.38\", \"A\", 11, 1517516700]]"
                         }
                  },
        "progress":1.0
      }
    ]`

Comment: I made a codepen with the full json file https://codepen.io/robiminusmaximus/pen/JppVvm the pdns data we have been working with is [4] in the array

Comment: I created a codepen that should help clarify this a bit. 
 https://codepen.io/anon/pen/paaBmd

Comment: this.state.gvEntries is the "pdns" array in your JSON blob

Comment: This is so wonderful thank you!  I’m still not able to reach the blob running on my local server for some reason but if I hard code it like your example it does seem to work. I’ll keep messing with it.

Comment: Excellent.  I would suggest looking into the way you're fetching and setting your data into state as I believe your issue probably lies there.

Comment: I hate to say this but i'm having another issue here. These output is putting everything in the array into a single cell??? Is there a way to separate the output into each item in the array to match the table header they're put under? God what a nightmare this has been sorry...

Comment: Hey man, no worries.  It's always nice to have a second set of eyes on things.  Check out the revised codepin: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/paaBmd

Comment: The problem is not the css, it's placing each item in the array under each table cell header. So right now the code you gave me spits all 5 items in the array out into one cell {element}. I need to break these up into <td>{element}?1</td>, etc... Am I making sense? Once again thank you so much!

Comment: I guess I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  In my codepen, the array is set up so every element is inside it's own cell (<td>{element}</td>).  And the array spans only 1 row.  Are you defining your own headers for this?  Because you're array is not set up in a key/value pair, there's only a value for each element.

Comment: No I think what you’ve done is correct but I’m trying to get each item within the array “198.11.168.38”, “11” etc... into their own table cell, not all of them in one cell. They are all labeled separately and shouldn’t be placed under just one table header as there should be 5 or so

Comment: I'm definitely not understanding what you're asking as in my codepen example each element is inserted into their own cell underneath a header: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/paaBmd

Comment: I must have not looked at the updated codepen, my apologies. One last question is there a way to assign specific headers to match each cell? You have each header with "header" and it's corresponding "i" parameter. What if I wanted to call/assign each header by a different name. Thanks again!

Comment: Just hardcode the headers in instead of using array.map.  Here's the updated codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WMzNYV

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could mark my answer as the correct answer if I was able to help you with your issue. :)